# Calling Runtime.getRuntime().exec multiple times

Tags: java, bash

I have a task that needs to happen several thousand times. In order to submit this task i am making a system call from a java program

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec()
```

My question is: is it more efficient to make one call to `Runtime.getRuntime().exec()` and have the system make a call to a bash script that runs my command several thousand times or is it more efficient to call `Runtime.getRuntime().exec()` itself several thousand times from within my java program?

Comment: In general the best answers to this question come from profiling within your application. Most importantly because that also answers the more important question; does it matter (if it changes your total run time by 0.1% it doesn't matter which is faster)

Comment: I would say either (a) use a loop in the bash script to do your 1000 tasks, or (b) move the task into java, and do it with 1000 threads. One thing's for sure: asking the O/S to setup & tear down 1000 processes has a cost which looping or threads does not. But its cost might be marginal compared with how long these tasks take to run, so also ask yourself if it's really worth the trouble.

Comment: The task cannot be completed from within java unfortunately. It is a call to a third party software that my company uses. This third party software does have a java api but, it does not work very well. That is why i am doing a system call. I think what might even be better is to have the java program call out to a perl script that will multithread my 1000 calls.